# Can I update a part of HDF5 file using h5py python library?

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

Can't find any command at http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/file.html to do that.

Comment: I don't understand this question. Of course you can "update" hdf5 files. That's the whole point of this library. Do you mean updating partial datasets? You can do this with indexing: dataset[10:15] = somedata. But that's all in the docs.

Comment: Thx, looks like I missed something in the docs.